# Why is my simulation of the Earth orbiting the Sun producing inaccurate force values?

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I'm trying to make a simple Python simulation of the Earth orbiting around the sun, and I don't know why my code is calculating the wrong force values. I'm noticing that the orbit radius is changing in magnitude - even though this should simulate a circular orbit. I know it's because the magnitude of the force vector is changing, but I'm not sure why it is.

I'm attempting to use the following formula to calculate the force values...

[image: Vector Form of Newton's Universal Law of Gravity]

I'm using the Numpy module and discrete time-steps to calculate future force values. I have a Planet class with a method called update_position() that takes in a Planet object as an input and calculates the force on the planet created by the passed in Planet object.

```py
TIME_STEP = 0.01
G = 6.67430e-11

class Planet:
    def __init__(self, x_position, y_position, x_velocity, y_velocity, mass):
        self.r_position = np.array([x_position, y_position], dtype = 'float64')
        self.velocity = np.array([x_velocity, y_velocity], dtype = 'float64')
        self.mass = mass


    def update_position(self, other):
        force = -1 * G * self.mass * other.mass * (self.r_position - other.r_position) / np.power(np.linalg.norm(self.r_position-other.r_position),3)
        self.velocity += force / self.mass * TIME_STEP
        self.r_position += self.velocity * TIME_STEP
```

Below, I create earth and sun Planet objects with real data. I then repeatedly call the update_position(sun) method on earth to calculate its new position.

```py
earth = Planet(x_position = 149_597_870_700, y_position = 0, x_velocity = 0, y_velocity = 29_784.8, mass = 5.972e+24)
sun = Planet(x_position = 0, y_position = 0, x_velocity = 0,y_velocity = 0,mass = 1.9891e+30)

...

while running:
    earth.update_position(sun)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I have. I printed out the value of force on each loop. On the first loop, it prints the correct value, but after that it starts straying further and further away from what I would expect it to be, and I'm not sure why it's doing that. I'm not sure if it's some sort of bug or If I implemented the formula incorrectly.

Comment: print all variables, not only `force`, and compare with calculations on paper. Of course there can be other problem: `float` is not ideal - it can't keep every value, so it can round some values and it can make (bigger and bigger) mistakes in calculations.

Comment: Your formula looks correct, so I see two possible reasons. (i) You are using the Euler integration method which is fairly inaccurate and will lead to Earth "overshooting" the intended circular orbit. (ii) If you've plugged in mean observed values for initial orbital radius and velocity, just be aware that the trajectory will not necessarily be circular with these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything particularly wrong with your formulation ... except that the timestep is excessively small compared with the time of a single orbit of the earth. You would have to do over 3 billion timesteps to complete an orbit if dt=0.01. I suspect the problem is that the difference between what you are adding to x or y at each timestep is so tiny compared with x or y themselves that the error in these floating-point additions becomes crucial.

The following code - with timestep 1 hour (=3600 seconds) - confirms that the orbit is circular. If you think otherwise then please show runnable code.

Note that to force a circular orbit make sure that your initial conditions give the correct centripetal acceleration: GMm/r^2 = mv^2/r (yours seem OK).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

TIME_STEP = 60.0 * 60       # one hour
G = 6.67430e-11

class Planet:
    def __init__(self, x_position, y_position, x_velocity, y_velocity, mass):
        self.r_position = np.array([x_position, y_position], dtype = 'float64')
        self.velocity = np.array([x_velocity, y_velocity], dtype = 'float64')
        self.mass = mass

    def update_position(self, other):
        force = -1 * G * self.mass * other.mass * (self.r_position - other.r_position) / np.power(np.linalg.norm(self.r_position-other.r_position),3)
        self.velocity += force / self.mass * TIME_STEP
        self.r_position += self.velocity * TIME_STEP

earth = Planet(x_position = 149_597_870_700, y_position = 0, x_velocity = 0, y_velocity = 29_784.8, mass = 5.972e+24)
sun = Planet(x_position = 0, y_position = 0, x_velocity = 0,y_velocity = 0,mass = 1.9891e+30)

num_t = int( 365.25 * 24 * 3600 / TIME_STEP + 0.5 )   # one year, give or take

x, y = [], []
for n in range( num_t ):
    earth.update_position(sun)
    x.append( earth.r_position[0] )
    y.append( earth.r_position[1] )

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.plot( x, y )
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]